# BCrypt in jdbctemplate map query

Tags: spring

```
@Override
public boolean validar(String login, String password) {     
    Map<String, Object> map = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(queryPorLogin, login);
    if(map.equals(password)) {
        return true;
    }else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering how I can do this password verification with the bcrypt method

```
BCrypt.checkpw(password, rs.getString("password"))
```

Comment: Maybe this? if(BCrypt.checkpw(password, map.values().toString())) {
   return true;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(map.equals(password)) - this will internally compares two maps by comparing both entry set either they are same with same mapping or not. so map and string can never be equal.

So first get String pwd= map.get("password"); and 
then check if(pwd!=null && pwd.equals(password))

**Now coming to BCrypt Implementation:**-

```
private final int logRounds=5; // It will be between 4 to 31

public String hash( @PathVariable("pwd") String  password) {
    return BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(logRounds));  // You will Store Hash into database.
}
```

and for verification:-

```
 BCrypt.checkpw(password, hash);    // here hash value you will get from database
                                    // password that user have entered
```

Although this is just basic example and can be included complex hashing strategies.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it would be better if you will use `BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword)` from spring-security module. Also this module has feature for checking password behid this scenes. You just need to dig a little bit for some tutorial.